# Apply Up Vector to look at vector

Tags: python, math, vector, matrix

Can anyone please help me apply or understand how to apply an up vector to a look at vector matrix? This is how I am currently working out my look at vector. Please let me now if this is wrong but it seems to work ( just with out being able to choose an up vector for my object):

```
pos1 = # a random vector
pos2 = # a random vector

vec3 = (pos2-pos1).GetNormalized() 
vec2 = vec3.Cross(Vector(0,1,0)).GetNormalized() 
vec1 = vec3.Cross(Vector(1,0,0)).GetNormalized() 
new_mx = Matrix(pos1,vec1,vec2,vec3)
```

This currently works great in that I am able to make an object point in the direction it is moving randomly in 3D space, although when it is going in negative numbers or 180 on an angle it has been heading in, the object turns upside down. How would I give it an up vector ie +Y to apply to this new matrix? Like a fish swimming around, its fin always points up for example. Any help or points would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is, you want to cross your `vec2` and `vec3` to get your final direction:

```
pos1 = # start location
pos2 = # location to look at
up = # specified up vector

vec3 = (pos2 - pos1).GetNormalized()  # "lookat" vector
vec2 = vec3.Cross(up).GetNormalized()  # "right" vector
vec1 = vec2.Cross(vec3).GetNormalized()  # different from above
new_mx = Matrix(pos1,vec1,vec2,vec3)
```

Depending on your coordinate conventions, you may need to change the sign of `vec1` above to match the orientation of your hardwired coordinates.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Please excuse my lack of understanding, but I don't know what you mean by change the sign of `vec1` as I think that is what I may have to do because with an `up = Vector(1,0,0)` I still get this upside down rotation. This image shows what I mean: http://i.imgur.com/J7MY2Gs.png

Comment: I have no idea what your coordinate conventions are, so I had a 50/50 chance of getting the sign right.  If your camera is upside down, use `vec3.Cross(vec2)` instead of `vec2.Cross(vec3)`.

Comment: Also, if your scene is then mirrored from the way you want it, use `Matrix(pos1,vec1,vec3,vec2)` instead of `Matrix(pos1,vec1,vec2,vec3)`.